# How can I retrieve the last but one Identity in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Know how can I retrieve the last but one **Identity** in Sql Server
that is `(n-1)`. I can get `@identity-1`. My problem is, when previous one is **deleted** the entire calculation will be wrong. Please help on this.

Comment: Whatever *problem* you're trying to solve, trying to obtain "last but one identity" isn't the solution. Can you outline the *broader* problem that you're trying to deal with?

Comment: I think for your use case Kapil's answer is match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the **maximum identity** of the table then you should use

```
 Select Max(IdentityColumn) from YourTable
```

If you want to get the **last identity** of your column then you should use

```
SELECT TOP(1) IdentityColumn FROM YourTable ORDER BY IdentityColumn  DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to find the **second next max value** of your identity column of a table. Query for that:

```
Select max(identityColumnName) from [tablename] where identityColumnName     
not in  (select max( identityColumnName) from [tablename])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it, However I beleive Damien is correct and you better describ the actual problem, since getting the 2nd last value of an identity column is probably not the solution:

```
SELECT TOP 1 IdentityColumn
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 2 IdentityColumn
    FROM YourTable
    ORDER BY IdentityColumn DESC
) t
ORDER BY IdentityColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

To just get the next to last identifier, you could also use LAG or LEAD in combination with TOP.

Note that this assumes that the ID is an INT that's auto-populated by an IDENTITY.
When the ID is an [uniqueidentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql) (aka Guid) then sorting it doesn't mean that the maximum value gives the last created record.

For example:

```
declare @T table (id int identity(1,1), value varchar(30));

insert into @T (value) values
('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E');

select top 1
lag(id) over (order by id) as BeforeTheLastId
from @T
order by id desc;

select top 1
lead(id) over (order by id desc) as BeforeTheLastId
from @T
order by id desc;

-- But to get the last Id, a max will do
select max(id) as LastId from @T;
```

Post scriptum test using a table that has an identity:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTest') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpTest;
create table #tmpTest (id int identity(1,1) primary key, value varchar(30), createdOn datetime2 default SYSDATETIME());
insert into #tmpTest (value) values ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D');

declare @MaxIdBeforeInsert int;
select @MaxIdBeforeInsert = max(id) from #tmpTest;
insert into #tmpTest (value) values('E');

select * from #tmpTest;

select 
IDENT_CURRENT('tempdb..#tmpTest') as CurrentIdentity, 
@@IDENTITY as IdentityVar, 
SCOPE_IDENTITY() as ScopeIdentity, 
@MaxIdBeforeInsert as MaxIdBeforeInsert;
```

Answer (score 0):

The current identity of the table can be retrieved by `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('<YourTableName>')`

As such, you need the below if you want the second max identity:

```
SELECT ISNULL(IDENT_CURRENT('<YourTableName>'), 1)-1
```